# Laravel : htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a Laravel project in which I need to write a custom function, but when I call this function Laravel says:

> Laravel : htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Here is my function:

```
public static function get_checkup_time(){
    $user_logged_in = Auth::user()->foreignkey_id; 
    $result = DB::table('doctors')
               ->select('checkuptime')
               ->where(['id'=>$user_logged_in])
               ->get();
    return $result;
}
```

And this is my `view` in which I am trying to invoke this function .

```
@if(Auth::user()->userrolebit ==2)
    {{
        DateTimeFormat::get_checkup_time()
    }}
 @endif
```

i don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You cannot just "print" arrays. Well, you can, but the result would certainly be meaningless. I'm pretty sure you want to extract `checkuptime` fromt he array.

Answer (score 1):

`where()` expects string as first parameter, so change this:

```
->where(['id'=>$user_logged_in])
```

to this:

```
->where('id', $user_logged_in)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return just checkup time you should do this in your method

```
public static function get_checkup_time()
{
    $user_logged_in = Auth::user()->foreignkey_id; 

    $result = DB::table('doctors')
               ->select('checkuptime')
               ->where('id', $user_logged_in)
               ->first();

    return $result->checkuptime;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**

Following a downvote, I've seen that mine wouldn't work as well because the `->get()` call should be replaced with `->first()` as in @Paul's answer. See my comment below.

---

The `$result` you are returning from the method is not a string.

Therefore `{{ DateTimeFormat::get_checkup_time() }}` is the one returning the error.

Returning something like `$result->checkuptime` should do it.

Comment: @Paul's answer is correct, mine would not work. Calling ```->first()``` instead of ```->get()``` is the key before returning a proper attribute. Good thing he beat me to posting an answer :)